# Is the dimension of eigenspace two when $\lambda \ge 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

let  $V= \{f:R \to R| f \text{ is continuously differentiable function}\}$ and  $T:V(R) \to V(R)$ such that $T(f) = f''$,then  which of the following is correct?

1) then  G.M of $\lambda= -1$ is $1$.

2) Then G.M of $\lambda= 2$ is $2$

3)  $\lambda =  -5$ is not an eigenvalue

4)  Dimension of eigenspace is two when $\lambda \ge 0$

I was taking $T(f)  = a_0+ a_1x+a_2x^2 +\ldots + a_nx^n $.
i take $n= 2$ that is $T(f) = a_0+a_1x +a2x^2$..
 $T'(f) =a_1+2a_2x$...and $T''(f) =2a_2$.  Here im  confused  i don't know from where  i have to start,,,,pliz help me  and  give me  any hints  or ifu have  time pliz give me the solution...i would be more thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of $V$ is not correct ! If $T:V \to V$, then $f''=T(f) \in V$. This means that $f''$ is continiously differntiable. But in general this is not the case !

Better choice: $V=C^{\infty}( \mathbb R)$.

Let $ \lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ and $f \in V$ such that $f''= \lambda f$

If $ \lambda=0$, then $f$ has the form $f(x)=ax+b$.

If $ \lambda >0$,then $f$ has the form $f(x)=ae^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+be^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$.

If $ \lambda <0$,then $f$ has the form $f(x)=a \cos(\sqrt{-\lambda}x)+b \sin(\sqrt{-\lambda}x)$.

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: thanks alots @Fred......let me Try.....

Comment: once again thanks a  lot @Fred i got it

Comment: @fred 2 and 4 are right answers. Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct !

Answer (score 1):

Hint to get you started:

Suppose $$Tf = \lambda f,$$

then we have $$f''=\lambda f.$$

This is a second order linear differential equation, try to solve for $f$ in terms of $\lambda$.

Comment: We have $T(f)=f''$ !

Comment: ooops, ok, now we have a second order differential equation. thanks for pointing that out.